# Should I use FTP or SFTP command?

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, ftp, sftp

I set up a FTP server using these instructions: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-and-manage-ftp-server-windows-10

If I wanted to SECURELY upload files to this server via CMD (Command Prompt), should I use the FTP command or SFTP command in CMD? What's the difference between the 2?

If I want to be more secured and protected, do I need to do anything else?

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: [Installing a secure FTP server on Windows using IIS](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_ftps_server) would seem more what you are looking for for windows. If you have an old computer you no longer use (it can be the oldest 64-bit box) or even a raspberrypi. There are a host of options available for creating secure ftp servers with either VSFTP, or a web server like nginx or apapche over https. Up to you, but those are options to consider.

Comment: Be aware Windows' FTP command doesn't do passive FTP so can't be used with firewalls.

Answer (score 3):

FTP (like http) is unencrypted. FTPS adds encryption (like https).

The walkthrough you linked to is for ftp, and specifically turns security (SSL) off, so even if you can connect via ftps it still wont be encrypted - which means any party between you and the server can intercept the traffic (and get your password).

In order to secure your connection you would need to change to ftps and require a cert.  An alternative is to set up a VPN server on your ftp server and then connect to ftp across the VPN.  Another solution would be to drop ftp and implement ssh (sftp or scp) transfers.

Comment: I think you got the protocols the wrong way around – FTPS is the one which adds TLS, and SFTP is the one which goes via SSH.

Comment: @user1686 ta. Ive updated my answer